# Use Micosoft Owin authentication to login using MS Account belonging to an oranization as well as use local db credentials

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin, forms-authentication

We have an old ASP.NET MVC application that is running on .NET 4.6 using SQL Server with connectivity established through ADO.NET and for login using forms authentication by generating a `FormsAuthenticationTicket`.

But now we want our organization users to be able to login using their MS 365 accounts but for external users the existing mechanism of logging in should keep working.

I updated the web app to .NET 4.8 as per directive available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-web-app-aspnet-sign-in . In order to enable this I have to disable the forms authentication which I did.

But how do I generate claim and authorize external users by validating their credentials from local database. Even after using multiple methods the system doesn't log these users.

Thanks

I followed the code available at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/quickstart-web-app-aspnet-sign-in